# Windows Tablet PC Keyboard blocks application

Tags: winforms, windows-8, keyboard, tablet-pc

I have created a Windows Form application (with MetroUI) for a Windows Tablet PC. The problem is that some dialogs are full screen.

When the user clicks on an input field which is located in the middle or at the bottom, the on-screen keyboard completely blocks the input field and the user is unaware of the input until the keyboard is hidden.

Is there a way I can show the user the input field during the input process (while the keyboard is still on screen). For instance whenever a user selects and input field in iOS or Android, the application tends to move upward to make way for the keyboard.

Comment: Are scrollbars an option on your full screen dialog?  If so, then you will likely have to resize the dialog to fit the available screen space not covered by the keyboard.  After the resize scroll bars will be present then you could use the native `ScrollToControl` function.  Dynamically figuring out what the available space is after the keyboard display might  be the hardest part since every screen can be a different size.

Comment: There's no other way apart from resizing the whole dialog? The keyboard takes more than half of the screen

Comment: In Windows 8 you may have some other keyboard options.  It doesn't solve you exact question but it is an option so that the keyboard is moving.  Check out [this link](http://win8room.net/en/2012/12/19/2489.html).  Otherwise you could bring up another modal form above the keyboard somewhere that would duplicate the active control on the main form so the user can see their input.